# Get messages from external user with graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I invited a user with email `unitest@outlook.com` to my Microsoft AD/tenant and I linked my current subscription to him.

This is how it looks:

[image]

But when I query that user for its messages I get no results:

```bash
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/51e7c5a3-ca7e-4ac6-b9fb-8e2858b9f077/messages

{"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('51e7c5a3-ca7e-4ac6-b9fb-8e2858b9f077')/messages", "value": []}
```

Is it not possible to get the messages from that external (but imported) user?

Comment: I'm afraid yes... [this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) will get the messages in the signed-in user's mailbox. Hence, for this user, if he had a mailbox which address is xx_outlook.com@xx.onmicrosoft.com, then using this api should get the response. But obviously what you want to get is the messages stored in outlook...

Comment: I am able to get user's messages if those users are within my tenant. I have not been able to access a user's messages if that user is part of a different tenant, even when I import/invite (not sure if that is the correct term) him.

Comment: yes sir, that's the expected behavior.